# Jquery get not working from inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have the following function:

```
$('#calendar_appointment_technician_id').change(function(){
    var technician = $('#calendar_appointment_technician_id').val();
    var date = $('#date').val();
    var id = $('#calendar_appointment_id').data("id");
    var response = $.get("/update_appointment_times?technician="+technician+"&date="+date+"&id="+id);
    $('#appointment_times').html(response.responseText);
  });
```

Which does a get request when a option dropdown changes. This is because the appointment times  will change if you change your technician. This code gives the following response:

```
Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
```

And most importantly, no response text. Now running this code in the chrome dev tools on the page:

```
var technician = $('#calendar_appointment_technician_id').val();
    var date = $('#date').val();
    var id = $('#calendar_appointment_id').data("id");
    var response = $.get("/update_appointment_times?technician="+technician+"&date="+date+"&id="+id);
    $('#appointment_times').html(response.responseText);
```

That code gives me a response text and the response looks like:

```
Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
```

Why does this work fine outside of the function but from within the get doesn't even seem to properly fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `.get()` method is async therefor you need to make sure it has completed before trying to use the return data.

`$.get()` returns a [`jQuery.promise`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) interface which we can use detect when the get request has completed.

```
var response = $.get("/update_appointment_times?technician=" + technician + "&date=" + date + "&id=" + id);

response.then(function (response) {
    $('#appointment_times').html(response)
});
```

Comment: I did the following: var response = $.get(url);
    response.then(function (){
      alert("whatever!");
    }); 

and i can see that the get request runs in my logs but that alert never fires.

Comment: @Greggawatt If a valid response is not returned `.then()` is not called. Try doing `response.always` and see if the alert fires.

Comment: Yeah it fired using .always

Comment: @Greggawatt Does your request complete successful with a valid response?

Comment: `Rendered calendar_appointments/_get_available_times.js.haml (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 600.7ms (Views: 3.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)` Seems like it. But now pasting that 600ms seems like a long time.

Comment: Ok so i added setTimeout function that seems to have helped.

Comment: @Greggawatt Im not sure why `.then()` is not working it's usually because of a bad response, but you can use `.always()` instead or stick with your `setTimeout` if you prefer that.